# Groovy MetaProgramming - How to override all methods of a class

Tags: reflection, groovy, metaprogramming

I'ld like to wrap all methods of a class a generic way. So I assume I don't know the methods the class is implementing and AOP is not an alternative.

Groovy metaprogramming allows to redefine methods even with parameters but how to do that when you get a list of parameters from reflection.

```
someClass.metaClass.methods.each { method ->
    someClass.metaClass.'${method.name}' =  { /* how to define parameters knowing I get them from method.parameterTypes */

    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: What is it you want to do?  If this is a short-lived thing, you could use a `ProxyMetaClass`

Comment: In fact I want to prevent the defined method to be called based on some criteria...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about `invokeMethod` ?

**Update**: As @Tim commented, you can use `getMetaMethod` to execute the old method:

```
class A {
  def methodA(String a) { "executing methodA..." }
  def methodB(String b, Float c) {}
  def methodC() {}
}

A.metaClass.invokeMethod = { String method, args ->
  def ret = delegate.class.metaClass.getMetaMethod(method, args)?.invoke( delegate, args )
  "[intercepted $method] $ret"
}

def a = new A()

assert a.methodA("a") == "[intercepted methodA] executing methodA..."
```

Comment: And then how would you invoke the method before redefinition?

Comment: I tried with redefining invokeStaticMethod but it doesn't work... or i'm doing it wrong

Comment: Thx for the help, I got something that works for existing methods... How could I do that when the called method is handled by the invokeMissingMethod definition?

Comment: @Fiftoine, i think that's a subject a for a new question :-). And that is very aspect-ish. You wanna intercept the interception.

Comment: Yeah @WillP, actually I want to override all grails domain object methods to secure them... And as grails inject a lot of dynamic methods using methodMissing, i'd like to intercept that too...